# What audio output is "communication" referring to in Google Hangouts?

Tags: google-hangouts

What audio output is "communication" referring to in Google Hangouts ?

[image]

I don't have a playback device with that name:

[image]

[image]

Communication tabs:

[image]

Comment: What does the Communications tab show? What happens when you select Communications in Hangouts?

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise good catch, I guess it switches to the "communication" mode. It is the first time I notice this Microsoft Windows feature.